# Why regression model coefficients can be different when they are plotted/displayed in the forest plot

Tags: r, r-forestplot, metafor

I am trying to carry out a subgroup analysis by plotting the mixed effects model results in a forest plot using `metafor` in `r`. The forest plot shows the mixed effect model coefficients (estimates and confidence interval), however, the estimates and confidence interval values in the forest plot are different than the model results.

For example the model shows the estimates and confidence intervals as follows: g1 = 0.19 CI = [0.1228 ; 0.2679] and g2 = 0.22 CI = [0.1704 ; 0.2778] while in the forest plot the values differ: g1 = 0.24 CI = [-0.14 ; 0.61] and g2 = -0.54, CI = [-0.67 ; -0.41]
Could anyone explain why this can happen?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Here it is: estimates: c(0.195353200692819, 0.224088756006418, -0.0351266597903724, 0.0777146218181036); standard error: c(0.0369987066795644, 0.0273823919107979, 0.0340908082663994, 0.0270838349406661); ci.lb: c(0.122837068126311, 0.170420254050693, -0.101943416196376, 0.0246312807711705); ci.ub: c(0.267869333259326, 0.277757257962143, 0.0316900966156308, 0.130797962865037)

Comment: This is not a reproducible example. You need to show (by updating the question, not in the comments) what you did. Provide code that somebody can run to reproduce the issue you are encountering.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I tried to create a reproducible example using ```dput``` but as the model output is large, I can't really show it. Is there any method for such cases?

Comment: Use a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example